# Can I ask one question on other stack exchange subforums?

Tags: support, allowed-questions

Is it allowed to ask the same question at different StackExchange sites?

Comment: Short answer: no!

Comment: Please also note that the Stack Exchange sites are **Question and Answer** sites, not *forums*. There is a fine but clear distinction between the two. A forum such as Reddit is mainly for discussion about answers, whereas SE Q&A sites are simply about the *question* and the *answer(s)*. Limited discussion may occur in the comments, but comments are second-class citizens and may be removed at any time, for many reasons.

Answer (score 4):

It's permitted only in the sense that you won't get banned. But don't do it, it even if the question is on-topic on both or all sites.

See [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu) which is part of the FAQ, so pretty official.

People who take the time to answer your question might not be happy to feel like they wasted their time answering when you have already received an answer elsewhere.

Comment: thanx, but what if question is not answered? For example in biology you tend to not answer, maybe I can post a question on other part, and delate original one?

Comment: @SSimon did you read the linked FAQ? That's covered in the second sentence of the answer...